# Internal wireless card setup VirtualBox on Mac

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, macintosh

Is it possible somehow to access the wifi of the Mac from VirtualBox. I haven't found any useful tutorial yet.
I'm using a Macbook Air late 2017

Comment: What way do you want to access it?

Comment: You can't find any useful tutorials because it generally can't be done. However, when you Google search this topic you _*do*_ find a whole lot of hits that explain it can't be done.

Comment: What way do you want to access it? Are you just trying to access the network, or something else? It can be set up so you can reach out (e.g. surf the web), or so others can also reach in (a server), or to give more access to the hardware (so wireshark can use it.

Comment: @0xSheepdog How can you say that it can't be done, when we don't know what OP is trying to do?

Comment: What way do you want to access it?

Comment: im trying to access it as a wireless card in linux so I have something like wlan0.

Comment: OK so you want to access a wireless network adaptor as a wireless network adaptor (not as a video adaptor), this is good. but What way do you want to access it?

Comment: oh it rains downvotes yay

Comment: how do you mean "what way"?

Comment: I have not down-voted you **yet**. I am asking what you are trying to do with the adaptor, as this will affect what you have to do, and thus the answer.

Comment: mainly capture packets for example, use tools like aircrack etc. and for that I need to access it from my Kali-linux vm from virtual box. Hope I understood you right.

Comment: If you add your clarification to the question the ping me with a comment, then I will up-vote.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Okay, fair enough. Assuming the intention is: 1- to connect to the host wifi-adapter from the Kali-Linux guest so they can run wireless security tools... it can't be done.  2- to connect to the wifi-adapter from the Kali-Linux guest so the guest can directly manage the wifi-adapter on the wlan... it can't be done.  3- to use a host network bridge so Kali-Linux can communicate outside the host without NAT, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the way you want to access it?

- Simplest: If you just trying to access the network, or something else? It can be set up so you can reach out (e.g. surf the web). Set up a virtual network adaptor attached to NAT.
- If you need it so others can also reach in (a server). Then use a bridged network, select the host adaptor to connect to.
- to allow wireshark to spy on the network, then use bridged with promiscuous mode.

Comment: Ah, my bad. Security tools that use promiscuous mode only would work in this case. Aircrack and the rest...not so much.